# How to put "My Documents" folder link in main menu in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

Don't remember exactly, but found, that main menu on my old Windows 7 computer contains link to "Documents" library, containing strange representation (all entries looks grouped by type and no way to ungroup). So, I need to click additionally to "My Documents" to see normal folder.

Is it possible to have direct link to folder (not to library) from main menu?

Comment: How about clicking with right mouse button on a 'My Documents' folder, choosing 'Include in library' and then choosing 'Create new library'. Will this solve your problem? This should give you new entry in the Menu.

Comment: You cannot really modify the Documents shortcut on the start menu as its built in. however you should be able to modify the grouping properties from within the View menu, if you press Alt + F to bring up the menu system at the top then go to View and then 'Group By' set to (None)

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to My Documents you should then be able to simply drag and drop the folder on to the quick menu on the left of the Windows Explorer view.